# Find the product of the maximal and the minimal values of the function

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y) = x -2y + 2xy$

in the region

$(x-1)^2 + (y + \frac{1}{2})^2 \leq 2$

I found one extreme value inside the region: f(1,1/2) = 1. However, I'm having trouble finding the values through the lagrange.

My constraint g would be $g = $(x-1)^2 + $(y + \frac{1}{2})^2 - 2 = 0 $

Comment: What does it mean "having trouble"? All you need to do is first partial derivatives and  solving the system of equations. You should check i.e example 4 from http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx (very good notes btw). Cheers!

Comment: @lemoid I found that $\lambda$ could either be plus or minus 1. However, I'm having trouble to get around the messy algebra.